# How to add a displayport to my motherboard?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, motherboard, displayport

I have motherboard - b150m-d3h-cf, which doesn't support DisplayPort.
I have got a newer monitor which support DisplayPort.
I want to upgrade my PC to have a DisplayPort. I don't want to completely replace the motherboard , CPU and RAM.
Is there a good option to add some component to the motherboard like add-in card or graphics card to add the necessary DisplayPort?

Comment: Buy a graphics card with DisplayPort on it?

Answer (score 1):

Video outputs are really part of the graphics adapter – not strictly part of the motherboard as such. Your motherboard only has them because it also has a GPU integrated (in the CPU).

All graphics cards for desktop PCs will bring their own outputs, usually multiple types. (Only laptops share their iGPU output with the discrete GPU, for various reasons like space saving.) So if you have a working PCIe x16 slot, find a GPU that has DP out and install it there.

Alternatively, if you don't need much in terms of capabilities, there are active DVI-D to DP converter adapters that would be cheaper than a whole GPU.

Comment: 1.  'only laptops'...mostly true. Though I am sitting next to a laptop which does not d that.      2. max DVI resolution is quite low, DVI -> DP will be an issue for 8K, 5K, 4K and possibly 2K screens.

Comment: @Hennes 1. True, some laptops have the external monitor output(s) connected to the dGPU only whereas the internal monitor can be driven by either one; 2. For the motherboard in question that supports only Intel 6th/7th gen CPUs, not really a problem ;)